# Show that there exists a $\gamma \in G$ so that $\phi$ is a grouphomomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $f: G \rightarrow G$ a function with the following characteristic:

$f(a)f(b)f(c)=f(u)f(v)f(w)$ for all $a, b, c, u, v, w \in G$ with $abc=uvw=1$.

Show that: There exist one suitable $\gamma \in G$ so that:
$\phi : G \rightarrow \gamma f(g)$ is a group homomorphism.

Ok here is a try:

$f(a)f(b)f(b^{-1}a^{-1})=f(ab)f(e)f(b^{-1}a^{-1}) \leftrightarrow$ 
$f(a)f(b)=f(ab)f(e)$

Let $\gamma :=1/f(e)$. Then:

$f(a)f(b)\gamma=f(ab)$.

But what I actually want is:

$f(a)\gamma f(b)= f(ab)$.

So if you chose $\gamma =1/f(e)$ then you showed that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. But that only works if G is abelian in my opinion...

Comment: So what is your question?  It kind of seems like you typed a homework problem in the box and expect the community to solve it for you.

Comment: i can proof it if the group is abelian, but it isnt

Comment: i dont know how to start

Comment: Include your proof of the abelian case in the question.  That gives us an idea of how much you know.

Comment: Here's a thought on how to start: The only information we have about $G$ is that it's a group and that $f$ is a function.  So the element $\gamma$ produced can only depend on $G$ and $f$.  Groups are only guaranteed to have one element: the identity $1$.  So you might try $\gamma = f(1)$.  But then $\phi(1) = f(1)^2$, and you need $\phi(1) = 1$.  So next try is $\gamma = f(1)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we must have $1 = \phi(1) = \gamma f(1)$, the only choice is $\gamma = f(1)^{-1}$. Now you can show that $\gamma$ commutes with everything:
$$f(a)f(1)f(a^{-1}) = f(1)f(a)f(a^{-1}) \Longrightarrow f(1)^{-1} f(a) = f(a) f(1)^{-1}$$
and you can finish.

Comment: This is the only possible choice of $\gamma$ because $\phi(1)=1$.

Comment: Edited to show that $\gamma$ is central.